# mysql query multple fields and assigning null to missing field

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query that needs to get data from two tables, "users", and "cust".  All users exist in "users", identified by the unique "userName" field.  They *may* exist in the "cust" table, under the same field name.

What I want my query to do is get certain fields of data from "users", and get a couple of fields of info from "cust", if they exist, but if they do not (and this is where my problem is), I need to assign a null value to the response.

e.g.:

```
SELECT a.userName,b.num,a.firstName,a.lastName,b.student,b.resident \
FROM users a, cust b WHERE a.userName = b.userName AND \
a.created > "2014-06-02" AND a.dupe IS NULL
```

So I have 758 entries in "users" that will match this query, but my query only returns 648 b/c 110 of the users are not in "cust".  How do I modify my query so that all 758 records will be returned, and the 110 users will have "num", "student" and "resident" as NULL values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `LEFT JOIN` is for:

```
SELECT a.userName, b.num, a.firstName, a.lastName, b.studen, b.resident
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN cust b ON a.userName = b.userName
WHERE a.created > '2014-06-02' AND a.dupe IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do use a right outer join. You are currently doing an inner join.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp